# Map 2 parent classes using AutoMapper

Tags: automapper

I'm trying to map 2 classes inheriting different base (but with common property). When I use Map, parent properties doesn't map automatically (which I think should based on inhertiance laws). Please suggest if I'm wrong somewhere:

```
  public class SourceBase
{
    public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }
}

public class DestBase
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }
}

public class ChildSource : SourceBase
{
    public string SourceName { get; set; }
}

public class ChildDest : DestBase
{
    public string DestName { get; set; }
}
```

Creating Maps

```
 AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<SourceBase, DestBase>()
                  .ForMember(dest => dest.Success, opt => opt.MapFrom(source => source.IsSuccess));

 AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<ChildSource, ChildDest>()
                  .ForMember(dest => dest.DestName,opt=>opt.MapFrom(source=>source.SourceName));
```

Using the Map

```
ChildSource ch = new ChildSource()
            {
                IsSuccess = true,
                SourceName = "user1"
            };

        var obj = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<ChildDest>(ch);
```

I expected IsSuccess as True and DestName as user1. But only SourceName gets set and IsSuccess remains false. If I use same name (IsSuccess) in both, it works which is because of automapping via name. But How can I use the existing format of different property names (but same types) in different class. I do not want to explicitly map parent properties while writing map for each child class.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell AutoMapper about the [inheritance](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Mapping-inheritance) by using the **Include** method:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SourceBase, DestBase>()
    .Include<ChildSource, ChildDest>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Success, opt => opt.MapFrom(source => source.IsSuccess));
```

Comment: Oh! The source and destination base class in my case are response DTOs from 2 layers which will inherited by large number of operations. Hence, I can not imagine adding all child mappings in parent's mapping. Instead, I think I have to add parent mapping as a part of creating child map (I hate repitition :(.. Thanks!